# Using React State values and Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, state

I have two react components:

```
<select> and <mytable>
```

which I need to use to build `<myInterface>`. Let S be a state of `<myInterface>` that needs to be modified by `<select>` and used by `<mytable>`. However, S needs to receive an initial value trough a call like:

```
<myInterface S = {some value} />
```

and just after that `<select>` needs to use that just entered value and after that only the state S.

Is there a way to do something like this in React? I can not modify 
    `<mytable>`  or   `<select>`
but they have related properties that could use S.
    I need to add: I am using something like:

```
var myInterface = React.createClass({
    ...
    render: function() {
        <div> 
             <select  ...... />
             <mytable ...... />
        </div>
    }
});
```

to build `<myInterface>`.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand that question, you want `<myInterface />` to receive props that it passes down to the `<select />`, but it must also state within `<myInterface />` in order for the select to be able to modify it?

Comment: EXACTLY!! but using the React.createClass

Comment: If I gave you answer with es6 syntax it should still apply no?

Comment: yes... it is ES6.. but my extension file says  jsx

Comment: well actually react.craeteClass is not es6, but wither way the principles should be the same.

Comment: Simply initialize the state with the value it gets from the props. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html#setting-the-initial-state

Comment: and use the state from the other components. !! right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here is an example with pseudo code of how you can solve this issue.

You have a container component that will render your `<myInterface />` it would look something like this.

```
class Container extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            myState: [1,2,4,5,6]
        }
    }

    redner() {
        return (
            <MyPage data={this.state.myState} />
        )
    }
}
```

This component initializes the state and passes it down as props to the child. The child which in your case would be `<myINterface />` would look something like this.

```
class MyPage extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            localState: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({localState: this.props.data});
    }

    render() {
        let table;
        let select;
        if(this.state.localState.length > 0) {
            table = <MyTabel data={this.state.localState} />
            select = <Select data={this.state.localState} />
        }
        return (
            <div>
                {table}
                {select}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This child component has its own state that it keeps track of which we start out with an empty array.

I have an if check in the render that checks if the localState array is full or empty. Only once it is full to I render the table and select. Then in the componentDidMount I set the state of the local state to be the value of the props being passed down. Now the the component re-renders and this time the localArray has data and now the table and select do render. Finally now that the data that is being passed to the select and table components, is state and not props, it can be modified.

Just one final point, you can of course initialize the localState to be the value of the props being passed in by the container in the constructor, but I chose to do this in componentDidMount because it is considered an anti pattern to set props to state in the constructor.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like that:

```
import { Component } from 'react';

export default class MyInterface extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: 'initial value'
        };

        this.setValue = this.setValue.bind(this);
    }

    setValue(value) {
        this.setState({ value })
    }

    render() {
        <div> 
             <Select  handleChange={this.setValue} />
             <MyTable value={this.state.value} />
        </div>
    }
}
```

So you can set the value calling the function `this.props.handleChange` on the `Select` component.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.setState({ value: value })` ?

Comment: @le_m on ES6 if you have a variable with the same name of the key you can just let the variable, but you can implicit declare the key name if you prefer. You will find more information about this [here](https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand)